# Push to different views with one BarButton

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, pushviewcontroller

I have my main window with a Navigation Bar and one BarButton in the top right corner.
I have a saved value, and depending on if it is TRUE or FALSE, I want to push to a different controller.
Now pushing to one is just Ctrl+Drag in IB, but what about if I want to choose beween views to push?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement a simple IBAction that you connect with your ~UIBarButton

```
-(IBAction)barButtonPressed {
     if (yourBoolean) {
          TrueViewController *trueViewController = [[TrueViewController alloc] init];
          [self.navigationController pushViewController:trueViewController animated:YES];
     } else {
          FalseViewController *falseViewController = [[FalseViewController alloc] init];
          [self.navigationController pushViewController:falseViewController animated:YES];
     }
```

Comment: I get the following ERROR: No visible @interface for 'UINavigationController' declares the selector 'pushViewController:' - I tried adding a UINavigationController *navigationController as an Outlet bet still get that message - any hint where I am getting lost?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've updated my answer from 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:trueViewController] to
[self.navigationController pushViewController:trueViewController animated:YES];